# YouTube Data API (v3) : Does Google OAuth2 authorization for YouTube uploads retrieval?

Tags: youtube-channels

Does Google OAuth2 authorization is necessary to retrieve YouTube channel uploads using YouTube Data API (v3) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OAuth 2.0 protocol** is required for authorizing access to private user data.So OAuth2 authorization will be necessary to upload on youtube using Youtube Data API